# Ruby,Rhomobile,JqueryMobile and Single Quote

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rhodes, rhomobile

In rhomobile, which is on ruby I have a parsing of file and saving to sqlite db such a code

```
Questions.delete_all()
file_name = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication::get_model_path('app','Settings'), 'questions.txt')
  file = File.new(file_name)

  file.each_line("\n") do |row|
    col = row.split("|")

   @question=Questions.create(
      {"id" => col[0], "question" => col[1],"answered"=>'0',"show"=>'1',"tutorial"=>col[4]}
    )


    break if file.lineno > 1500
  end
file.close
```

when in text in string there is single quote aka '  , for example an expression

```
It's  funny
```

Then after parsing, saving and populating I get

```
It�s  funny
```

Any idea how to solve this and where from it comes, from  Ruby, From sqlite or from what? how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I would check to make sure that your parsing isn't doing something funny. The Rhodes handles all of the necessary escaping in its ORM. I've never had any issues with quotes in the db.

Comment: Hey there Jared - it seems like you are a Rhodes / RhoMobile developer.  We are considering various mobile platforms and I am curious what you think of it.